# Windows 7 Office 2007 GPO install

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, microsoft-office-2007

I have a GPO that works fine for installing Office 2007 Pro Plus on Vista and XP but when it installs Office on Windows 7 somehow the office key does not get entered via the customized msp, and needs to be entered manually.  Has anyone else run into this? Any suggestions for a fix?  Its defeats the purpose of remote unattended install if I then have to run around entering the stupid key.

edit: I am sorry I should have specified I also have the config.xml file customized already. I have it set to display level none, completion no, suppress modal to yes accept eula to yes, the key put in and the company name and the username variable (%USERNAME%).

Answer (score 1):

I tought the deploy was supposed to run with the config.xml?

Anyways, I am running it with xml in our GPO deploy and it works flawlessly for xp/vista/win7.
We also ad swedish language support cuz we want it:)

put the folowing xml in config.xml in the ProPlus.WW folder, the run from the gpo:

\server\share\Office12\ProPlus.WW\ProPlus.msi

```
<Configuration Product="ProPlus">
  <Display Level="Basic" CompletionNotice="No" SuppressModal="No" AcceptEula="Yes" /> 
  <PIDKEY Value="YOUR KEY GOES HERE" /> 
  <COMPANYNAME Value="CompanyName" /> 
  <AddLanguage Id="match" /> 
  <AddLanguage Id="en-us" ShellTransform="Yes" /> 
  <AddLanguage Id="sv-se" /> 
</Configuration>
```

Im sorry this is not an answer to your question, tough it should work as a workaround for you.
Ps. if you want the installer to run compleately silent use the display level="none" instead of basic. Basic only gives you a progressbar.. ds.

[Technet link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179195.aspx)

Good luck!

Comment: I am sorry I should have specified I also have the config.xml file customized already.  I have it set to display level none, completion no, suppress modal to yes accept eula to yes, the key put in and the company name and the username variable (%USERNAME%).

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have the Enterprise version of Office 2007,aAnother thing to try is to use the Office Customization Tool and add the product key to the the customization file and then store the file in the updates folder.  There are also .adm files available from Microsoft that allow Group Policy to control a lot of extra features that aren't dealt with in the OCT.  I use this combination with a lot of success.
If you will upgrade anytime soon, Office 2010 is able to be activated via KMS.